# Wait for Tapestry effects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, synchronization, tapestry

we are using Tapestry 5.3.8 in our app. Integration tests are implemented using Selenium 2.53.1.

Sometimes, a Selenium test needs to wait for some action until it is completed. If Tapestry e.g. calls an AJAX requests, the test executes the following code to wait until the AJAX request is completed.

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>()
{
    @Override
    public Boolean apply(final WebDriver webDriver)
    {
        String js = "return window.Ajax.activeRequestCount";
        Long count = (Long) ((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript(js);
        return count.longValue() == 0;
    }
});
```

Now, let's consider the following snippet of Tapestry template:

```
<t:formfragment t:id="repeatedDate" element="fieldset" show="show" hide="fade" visible="dateRepeated">
    ...
</t:formfragment>
...
<t:checkbox value="dateRepeated" t:mixins="triggerfragment" fragment="repeatedDate"/>
```

When the appropriate check box is selected the fragment appears with the Tapestry effect "show".

Is there a way to wait for the completion of the effect in a Selenium test? In another words, is there some JavaScript expression that evaluates to `false` when the effect is in progress and to `true` when it is completed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transition effects are not related to an Ajax call and depend on the implementation.

So you could also try to wait for the count of effects to be zero:

```java
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>()
{
    @Override
    public Boolean apply(final WebDriver webDriver)
    {
        String SCRIPT =
          "return window.Tapestry.pageLoaded === true    " +
          "  && window.Ajax.activeRequestCount === 0     " +
          "  && window.Effect.Queue.effects.length === 0 " ;

        Object result = ((JavascriptExecutor)webDriver).executeScript(SCRIPT);
        return Boolean.TRUE.equals(result);
    }
});
```